# Technical Term for this behaviour?

Tags: arrays, stack

just a short question none of my colleagues nor "google" could answer:
I have implemented a stack/array with this behaviour:

1. Create stack/array with predefined size
2. Put object into stack/array
3. If predefined size is reached, the *oldest* object will be overwritten
4. When getting an object: Index 0 is oldest entry, Index  is newest entry

Everything works fine. It's just I don't know how to properly call this behaviour. What's the technical term for that kind of stack/array? (I called it CircleStack because I'm working internally with a wrapping pointer but shurely this is not the correct term ;-)).

Best

Comment: how is it a stack? doesnt look like last in first out.. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/circular-queue-set-1-introduction-array-implementation/ are you asking about circular queue/ring buffer?

Comment: perfect! I just verified it - now that I know what term to look for. So my implementation is basically a circular buffer with FIFO for getting objects out of it. Thank you. :-)